# Change each individual element style based on condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to change the background color of `select` element based on which option user selects. I have created this example https://codepen.io/lordKappa/pen/YzrEWXd and here the color changes but it also changes for all `select` elements not just for the one we changed.

```
  const [selectState, setSelectState] = useState("To-do");
  const [taskID, setTaskID] = useState();

  function handleDropdownChange(e) {
    var taskID = e.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-index");
    setTaskID(taskID);
    setSelectState(e.target.value);
  }

  if (selectState === "To-do") {
    selectStyle = {
      backgroundColor: "red",
    };
  } else if (selectState === "Done") {
    selectStyle = {
      backgroundColor: "green",
    };
  } else {
    selectStyle = {
      backgroundColor: "yellow",
    };
  }

  return (
    <div className="box">
      <div>
        {elementList.map((task) => (
          <div key={task.id}>
            <h1>{task.info}</h1>
            <select
              onChange={handleDropdownChange}
              data-index={task.id}
              style={selectStyle}
            >
              <option value="To-do">To-do</option>
              <option value="Done">Done</option>
              <option value="In progress">In progress</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Have you considered creating a select component where the style state is isolated in each one?

Comment: Yes you are right i did this and it works now thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The color changes an all dropdowns in the code-pen you provided because they all rely on the same piece of state. You either need to make the state for each dropdown be independent of each other, or separate the dropdown into its own component.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a state for tasks

```js
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([
   { id: 0, info: "Task 1", status: 'TODO' },
   { id: 1, info: "Task 2", status: 'TODO' },
   { id: 2, info: "Task 3", status: 'TODO' }
  ]);
```

Then, everytime you change the selectbox, update `status` inside `tasks` state

```js
function handleDropdownChange(e) {
    var taskID = e.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-index");
    setTasks(tasks.map(task => {
     if (taskID !== task.id) return task;
     task.status = e.target.value
     return task
    }));
  }
```

Finally, when rendering tasks we only need to check the task's status and change style

```js
{elementList.map((task) => {
// put your condition here ....
return (
          <div key={task.id}>
            <h1>{task.info}</h1>
            <select
              onChange={handleDropdownChange}
              data-index={task.id}
              style={selectStyle}
            >
              <option value="To-do">To-do</option>
              <option value="Done">Done</option>
              <option value="In progress">In progress</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        )
})}
```